# What is the difference between method="get" and $_GET?

Tags: php, html, http

The question is pretty self explanatory - to my understanding `method="get"` is the HTML functionality of `PHP's $_GET`. Would I be correct in this assumption or is there a distinction?

Comment: `methode="get"` sends http request while `$_GET` receives http request

Comment: This should clear up the superglobal: `$_GET`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"methode=get" means you use the GET. That means when you send your value , your variables will be saved in the URL like

https://example.com/file.php?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2

With PHP's $_GET you receive the values

Example

```
 $value1 = $_GET['parameter1'];
```

Now your $value1 will be the same value like "value" you sended

Answer (score -1):

The terms "HTTPS GET" and `$_GET` in PHP refer to different concepts:

1. HTTPS GET:

   - HTTPS (Hypertext Transfer Protocol Secure) is a secure version of HTTP used for secure communication over the internet.
   - GET is one of the HTTP request methods used to request data from a specified resource.
   - HTTPS GET, in the context of web development, refers to making an HTTP GET request to a web server over a secure HTTPS connection. This is a way to retrieve data from a web server.
2. `$_GET` in PHP:

   - `$_GET` is a superglobal array in PHP that is used to collect data sent to the server via HTTP GET requests.
   - When a user submits data to a PHP script through the URL, such as through query parameters like `?name=John&age=30`, PHP automatically populates the `$_GET` array with this data.
   - Developers can access and use the values in `$_GET` to process the data sent by the client.

In summary, HTTPS GET is a protocol for securely requesting data over the web, while `$_GET` in PHP is a built-in array for handling data sent via HTTP GET requests within PHP scripts.

Comment: You shouldn't post AI hallucinations here